# Financial Service Cloud relationship map in force.com platform

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, force.com, customization, financial-services-cloud

I'm looking out for  a FSC relationship map like component that I can use in a custom aura/lwc cmp (force.com platform).

[image]

I was not able to find any such existing lightning component in the standard library nor in recepies. Also I was not able to find any SLDS reference to build a custom one.

Any leads would be appretiated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever manager to get this down? I have to do this exact thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard component for this as far as I am aware of so you have to build your own.
You can use link in https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/client-management-with-financial-services-cloud/map-client-relationships to sign up for Developer Edition org with Financial Services Cloud.
Then look for this component in Accounts detail page.